# iOS Push Notifications Flow

Tags: ios

I'm working on push notification flow but not getting exactly how to handle it. I need a simple explanation, when push notification comes, which delegate is called

1. When user tap on push notification label
2. When user tap on App icon when push notification comes

I'm unable to maintain to my app application state, for me the flow should be like:

1. **When user tap on push notification label**: It should open a particular viewcontroller
2. **When user tap on App icon when push notification comes**: It should open same viewcontroller from where app goes in background

How I can achieve this in Xcode 8.1/iOS 10.1.1?

Also I'm using background mode remote notification and background fetch.

Answer (score 2):

In AppDelegate.m used it to check where user tap icon

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    //Handle notification when the user click it while app is running in background or foreground.
    if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {

        NSLog(@"Inactive - the user has tapped in the notification when app was closed or in background");
        //do some tasks


    }
    else if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {

        NSLog(@"application Background - notification has arrived when app was in background");

    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"application Active - notication has arrived while app was opened");

        //do tasks


    }


}
```

Comment: This is working in iOS 10.1.1 :) , i don't now why it is not working  in ios 10

Comment: i'm using background mode remote notification and background fetch. so didReceiveRemoteNotification: withCompletion is also there anything i have change??

Answer (score 0):

When a push notification sends from server a delegate call on app side but you have to register from app end by adding  registerForPushNotifications.

```
  - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
  { 

    //Handle notification when the user click it while app is running in background or foreground.


    //Where userinfo is a dict. It has the data sent from server

  }
```